# Should I edit the outcome into the question, or answer my own question?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, editing, self-answering

As far as I know, it is okay to answer your own questions. It is also recommended to show your progress with a question, and this is easily accomplished by editing the question itself and incorporating the progress there.

When should I answer my own question and when should I edit the outcome into the question? (Obviously, if someone provided a satisfactory answer, then accepting it is more elegant, so suppose nobody provided a satisfying answer, or combining several answers gives a good one, or some scenario like those.)

Comment: There's a drawback to accepting your own answer, which is that it doesn't appear above other answers that have more votes. Late replies also tend to get fewer votes than earlier ones, so if you think you've got the best answer, it may still be buried at the bottom.

Comment: Hmm, this seems related to this Q&A: [“Update: here's how it worked out…” Where does it go?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7544/22566)

Answer (score 13):

- If what you did was mostly different from the other answers and solved your problem, post your own answer and accept it. There's a waiting period for self-accepting, but other than that it's fair game.

  The goal is to get the best answer to have the green checkmark next to it.
- If what you did was mostly the same as an existing answer with a few tweaks, accept that answer and either post a comment to it or edit it to show what you changed.
- If you don't consider what you're doing to solve your problem, post it as an edit to your question, with an explanation of why it isn't a solution.

Answer (score 2):

It strikes me as appropriate when you actually decide on a course of action.  Certainly with the "best answer" button it identifies the closest answer to your desired solution, but it never hurts to put a synopsis of how the other responses led you to a course of action as well.